# Is there any way to calculate maximum reload efficiency for the Huntress?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

The way reloading with the Hunter/Huntress works is that it takes longer to reload the less ammo you have. So with a clip of 30, it takes longer to reload if I'm down to 0 ammo than it takes if I'm still at 15 or so.

I've started to level a DPS Huntress with some friends, and I'm wondering if there's any way for me to figure out when I should reload in order to maximize my DPS. To that end, I'm wondering the following:

1. Is there tactical reloading for the Huntress? If I reload with 1 shot left, will it take a shorter amount of time than if I reload after completely running out?
2. Do reloading times vary between different weapons, or is it static?
3. Is there any concrete formula for determining when it's most efficient to reload based on your maximum clip size?

Basically, is there such thing as a formula that you can output into a table/chart so you could compare the amount of time it takes to reload when you have X ammo left based on Y clip size? Or are there reload times different for each weapon, making this too difficult to calculate with any accuracy?

Comment: There is also a stat on weapons themselves that gives you a +/- to reload time. The stat is called "Reload Speed Bonus". Depending on the weapon it will be either in the top row or in the bottom row. That adds in a lot of factors as when you upgrade the weapon, if it has this stat available it is one of the options you can choose to upgrade instead of the other standard stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload times are weapon-specific and are not dependent on the max ammo size of the weapon.

The reload speed stat is represented by the following icon:

[image: Weapon reload stat icon]

There is 'tactical reloading' (emptier clip == more time to reload). For proof, review the video below. Look specifically at the reload times at the beginning of the video when the clip is mostly full and at 1m13s when the clip is mostly empty:

The core of your question seems to be along the lines of "Will I spend more time reloading if I reload once when my clip is empty as opposed to twice when my clip is half empty". In the end, the reload time is essentially the same. For optimal gameplay, reload when you have enough time to spare to reloading before you have to fire again.

In terms of trying to calculate an exact figure (which is the subject of your question),  I haven't seen a way that doesn't involve diving into the code for the game. Trendy offers the code as [downloadable content on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/202522/) should exact figures be very important to you. However, I think that simply knowing that different weapons reload at different rates is sufficient. Once you get familiar with the reload rate of your specific weapon, it will become intuitive to figure out if you have enough time to reload or if you need to shoot more first.

Comment: I know that it takes less time if I reload after expending less ammo, but that link doesn't show me if takes less time to reload after expending all ammo rather than having 1 ammo left. Some games (usually FPS games) have longer reload times based on if you emptied the clip fully or not. Regarding the point about code diving, that was partially the purpose of asking this question, hoping someone may be able to figure that out as I don't know anything about coding. Perhaps I'll throw a bounty on this...

Comment: After leveling my Huntress to 70, I now realize that even if someone were to examine the code, the resulting tabled information would be way too unwieldy to try to put together, necessitating variables for each reload speed buff, max ammo, etc., so accepting this!

Answer (score 0):

While I can't answer the math portions of the question, I can answer bullet point 2.

Reloading times vary significantly between weapons. I had a weapon with 8 max ammo that took longer to reload than any other weapon I'd seen, up to 60+ ammo. I haven't played the huntress extensively, but reload times definitely vary.